# Communictating between classes using Jpanel, repaint() method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I have a class "GUI" that extends JPanel. I have another class "Buttons" that extends JFrame. I'm trying to have the JFrame class call a method "clearScreen()" in the JPanel class when the when a JButton "clearB" is pushed on the JFrame. 
The only way I could make this work was by building the object for the JPanel class "GUI" right in the actionlistener for the JButton:

```
clearB.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        GUI g = new GUI();
                        g.clearScreen();

                    }
                }
            );
```

But then when I called the method clearScreen(), which looks like this:

```
public void clearScreen(){
        xs.clear();
        ys.clear();
        count = 0;
        repaint();
    }
```

NOTHING HAPPENED. I'm guessing it's because the repaint() method wasn't working for some reason unknown to me.
Someone PLEASE show me an easier, working way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish here.
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your ActionListener isn't working is because the GUI object that you create in there is a **new** GUI object, one that is completely unrelated to the GUI object that is displayed, and so calling the `clearScreen()` method on the non-displayed GUI instance will have no effect on the displayed GUI instance.

The solution is for your Buttons class to hold a **valid reference** to the visualized GUI object and call methods on this reference. The reference can be passed via a setter method or constructor parameter.

i.e.,

```
public class Buttons {
  private GUI gui;

  public Buttons (GUI gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
  }

    // in some ActionListener code...
    gui.someMethod();
}
```

A couple of comments:

- It is unusual that you should have to have a class that extends JFrame. Myself, I try to avoid doing this unless necessary, but rather usually create my JFrames from the JFrame class itself, and only when needed.
- I'm a little surprised that your main window class doesn't already have a GUI variable, since it likely displays the GUI instance.

Comment: Going down memory lane -- wow I was such a noob two years ago